# How to get the executable path from a Managed DLL

Tags: dll, path, c++-cli, executable

I have a managed DLL (written in C++/CLI) that contains a class used by a C# executable. In the constructor of the class, I need to get access to the full path of the executable referencing the DLL. In the actual app I know I can use the Application object to do this, but how can I do it from a managed DLL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
```

or

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

or

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
```

Depending on your need.

Then use Location or CodeBase property (I never remember which one).

Comment: Use the CodeBase property after calling one of these methods.

Answer (score 5):

@leppie: Thanks - that was the pointer I needed.

For future reference, in C++/CLI this is the actual syntax that works:

```
String^ appPathString = Assembly::GetEntryAssembly()->Location;
```

`GetExecutingAssembly()` provided the name of the DLL

`GetCallingAssembly()` returned something like System.Windows.Forms

`GetEntryAssembly` returned the full path, similar to `GetModulePath()` under Win32.

Comment: Thanks for giving the details for each. It saved me some googling!